# API Proxy - Error while fetching object

Tags: apigee

When I open the details window on any of my API Proxies using the APIGee Developer Dashboard, I get two error messages

> Error while fetching object: No server entry found with ID *long token goes here*

and

> Server Error: No server entry found with ID *same long token goes here*

The page still seems to function partially, but this prevents me from seeing my API proxy deployments and proxy information, or from tracing calls to the API.

I can't figure out what triggered this error - I don't see any recent config changes and the API proxy and the endpoint services are up and running. There's no reference to 'Server Entry' anywhere on the config page or in the help, which makes it hard to know where to start when fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

Please see here: http://status.apigee.com/

This could be related to the platform release in flight.

You can subscribe to this for future updates too.

If the issue still persists, do raise a support ticket http://apigee.com/about/support/request-support

Comment: If [this is you](https://www.linkedin.com/in/ikqureshi), then you should disclose your affiliation in your answers and probably also in your user profile.